# How to tell if an employer has been banned from Apple's App Store?

Tags: apple, appstore

I have a potential employer who desperately wants to produce an app, but for some reason they are refusing to get a $99 company dev account, saying the application process would be too difficult and tedious. And yet they want me to create a single-person account. I think they've been banned from the Apple's app store but how can I verify it?

Thanks.

Comment: I would reject any client who seems "desperate" on principle.  Its not fun working for people on a sinking ship and it always seems to cost you in the long run.

Comment: The risk with a client who thinks application to the iOS program is "too difficult", is that they might find the same "difficulty" true with paying your invoice.

Answer (score 15):

You could offer to fill out the application for them, using their information. That removes the obviously bogus 'difficult, tedious' argument. If they still refuse, tell them that you won't work with or for them if you can't trust them, and ask them for an honest explanation.